# Face post of a subcomplex complement

Tags: general-topology

Let $P$ denote the face poset of a simplicial complex, $\Delta$ the order complex of a poset, and $\simeq$ homotopy equivalence.  It's known that for any finite simplicial complex $\mathcal{K}$ that $\Delta(P(\mathcal{K}))\simeq\mathcal{K}$ (it's the barycentric subdivision).  See for example Bjorner's *Topological Methods*.  But instead suppose you have a finite simplicial complex $\mathcal{K}$ and a subcomplex $A\subseteq\mathcal{K}$. Can it be shown that $\Delta(P(\mathcal{K}\setminus A))\simeq\mathcal{K}\setminus A$?  The face poset of $\mathcal{K}\setminus A$ is well defined.  In fact $P(\mathcal{K}\setminus A)=P(\mathcal{K})\setminus P(A)$, but $\mathcal{K}\setminus A$ isn't actually a simplicial complex.  Also if this is true could the results be extended to regular CW-complexes?

Sorry if this question is really basic.  I'd be happy just to get a reference where stuff like this is worked out.  I haven't had really any luck in finding work on subcomplex complements.

Comment: Cross-listed on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/184324/face-poset-of-a-subcomplex-complement